# How to get a list of Gerrit changes that were self-reviewed

Tags: gerrit

In our Gerrit setup, it is possible that the author of a change gives his or her own change a +2 review (which is the default behavior of Gerrit). We would like to keep this behavior, but we would still like to have a review for these changes, even if they have already been merged.

So, I'm looking for a search filter that produces a list of **changes that only have a +2 from the change author** and not from any other account.

I don't care if this is a search filter for the Gerrit UI, or a query that works directly on the database. It doesn't have to be fancy, user-friendly or beautiful, as long as it produces a list of changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do, is running a search query:

```
label:Code-Review=+2,owner
```

This matches reviews for that label with that score, *by the owner*.

Two remarks when trying to customize this query:

- Changing this to `label:Code-Review=+2,uploader` seems not supported. So that means that someone else can push a new patch set and self-approve those changes, going unnoticed. See my feature request: [10425](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=10425).
- Changing this to more implicit 'approval' rather than '+2' with `label:Code-Review=ok,owner` implicitly restricts the results to open changes only.

See also: [Documentation: Searching Changes - Labels](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.0.2/user-search.html#labels) as well as the [Project Configuration - Label Configuration - setting `ignoreSelfApproval`](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.0.2/config-labels.html#label_ignoreSelfApproval) to prevent submission based on self-approvals.

Comment: Our older Gerrit 2.12 did not support this search filter, but after updating it works! I would have preferred a filter that does not include commits that are also +2'd by others, but this filter does the job if you keep track of the last commit in the list that was reviewed after the fact. Thanks!

Comment: And since we are a small company, we can use personalized search filters, like so: `author:mycolleague AND label:Code-Review=+2,owner AND NOT label:Code-Review=+2,myname` to get commits of my colleague that were +2'd by him but not by me.